# IIS 7 HttpLogging module config to don't log monitoring requests

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, logging

I need do configure IIS 7 logging module to don't log some requests like /working.html what I'm using for external monitoring IIS site (with basic http get/head requests using nagios or upstream failover proxy).

Problem that currently most of access log is filled by that monitoring requests and I want to don't log them all.

How can I make this configuration with native HttpLogging module. If not possible to do with it (looks like), then let me ask other ways to reach needed functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Advanced Logging Module](http://www.iis.net/download/AdvancedLogging) in IIS7 is meant for situations like yours.